# REQUEST: Windmill recordings

Tags: recording, request, sound-libraries, collaboration

Hi folks,

I've been enjoying Social Sound Design for many months now and find it to be an incredible resource for picking creative brains all over the world. What I haven't seen much of, however, is requests for sounds / offers of trades in return. Given the global nature of the Users here I think this is a no-brainer since many of you have access to ambiences and objects that the rest of us do not. Thus, my post -

I'm currently working on a project that has a rickety windmill-type contraption and am looking for alternate sounds to what I have already designed. To paint a mental picture, think:

- Very old, very large and barely holding
  together. *But* has to still be working and have a strong rhythmic
  motion to it.

Some recordings I think could work would be of:

1. Windmills
2. Grain mills / other types of mills
3. Water wheels
4. Spinning wheels
5. Ratchety factory machines
6. Antique machines not requiring a
   motor

I'm curious to see what you all have in your personal libraries, and if you'd be willing to share or trade? If so, what's the best way to exchange files? Vimeo, ftp or something else? Chime in, people -- let's get to tradin'!

Comment: Trade you some authentic old mill and such for some of those A10 jets you've got...

Comment: @Ryan, you've been awfully active on the board today ;). Sorry, those A10s are not mine to trade, but I do have lots of other stuff that may interest somebody out there. What's the best way for me to hear what you have? Vimeo? Something else?

Comment: @birdhousesound I'm not too far away from you. I can E-mail you MP3s and if you don't want to give up those A10s, let me sit in on the mix of what you're working on as a guest!!!

Comment: @birdhousesound CLARIFICATION: I'll e-mail you MP3s and if you like those sounds I'll get the 96/24 to you whatever way.

Comment: @birdhousesound Jay, check your e-mail :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As fantastic as it is to see the new breed of 'boutique' fx libraries emerging to challenge the established 'supermarket' brands, every good industry also needs a black market!  You can't beat a bit of old-fashioned bartering!

Best,

Michael

Answer (score 2):

What's your time frame? I don't have recordings on hand, but there are a few historic mills out here. I could call around and try to arrange a recording day.

Comment: @Steve Urban - if you get one arranged, give me a call. we can pool gear and mics and get tons of sounds. lol

Comment: @Shaun You read my mind. I'm thinking we should just do it regardless of if it works with birdhousesound's time frame or not.

Comment: @Steve - agreed!

Comment: @Steve, thanks so much for the offer. There definitely are some great mills in your area (especially that one in Rock Creek Park). Unfortunately I won't be able to wait for this request but I encourage both you and Shaun to go out and record together - we can talk again when you've finished mastering and see if we can work out a trade.

Answer (score 1):

I just did a quick search for 'windmill' and 'turbine' on Freesound.org. A number of files came up. If your project is non-commercial those files are free to use.
http://www.freesound.org/

Comment: @jgrzinich, thanks for checking. I searched there also and found some really great recordings.