# SoundSwap - trading sound effects

Tags: community, trade, sound-effects

This isn't really so much of a question as it is a heads up. I've added a new forum to my website called SoundSwap. All it's for is trading sound effects and nothing else.

I started thinking about it back when Jay put up [this post](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/2648/request-windmill-recordings). While I know Freesound.org is out there, a lot of us can't use sounds from there because of the legal stipulation that we credit the owners of the sounds (and there's no allowance for synchronization unless the sound has been modified). Freesound is a great site, but I thought that a more personal approach might be better for the community.

So, you can trade sound effects that you personally own. Not ones from a library you've bought, but ones you've recorded or synthesized. I have no idea how well the site will work out, but I figured it was worth giving it a shot. If nothing else, it may come in handy for people participating in the monthly challenges I run. ;)

Check it out when you get a chance:

http://soundswap.dynamicinterference.com

Comment: @Shaun:
What about swapping sound making devices, like Ableton racks I've made especially for generating a specific sound?

Comment: @Kurt - great idea. i'll add it to the categories.

Comment: @Shaun The site is timing out?

Comment: @Ade - I just visited to check on that issue, and it seems to be working fine. You still having issues? If so, what browser are you using, and I'll check that scenario.

Comment: @Shaun Must have been down for me, it's working now :)

Answer (score 1):

Great initiative!
On that spirit i started uploading wav files on soundcloud that you guys can download and (please!) use however you like.
If you could leave comments on how the sound could be better captured in any way i would appreciate it (feel free to be as brutal as you'd like)! I'm trying to choose location specific sounds, or things that i think (maybe wrongfully, yet there they are!) that might not be of easy access for one reason or another.

My user name is Filipe Chagas.

Just giving a little something back to the amazing community

Cheers everybody

Comment: I think i had a Karma attack on this one... Got 2 amazing Gigs today! Woot!

Answer (score 1):

Love the idea Shaun. I will try to participate and post some links to my stuff, even if I don`t know how good these samples really are =).

EDIT: one question that comes into my mind: I guess, I shouldnt link to my freesound profile becuase of the license right? I also have some samples uploaded at soundcloud, would it be better to paste links to these samples?

Comment: my thoughts were that people would use that site just to get in contact with one another. how they handle auditioning/transferring sounds is up to them...but i do think soundcloud is going to be the most useful resource at the moment for those functions

Comment: oops, and to answer your question, sure you can link to your freesound profile...they're your sounds. the license data that freesound.org makes people agree to is superseded by the rights of the owner. if you say it's ok for someone to use something, then it's ok. :)

Comment: that`s what I wanted to know =) thank you

Answer (score 1):

Cool idea Shaun! It'll be like Panini stickers in the playground. *Got, got, got, NEED!*

Comment: Can't remember what they're called, but I remember those 3rd and 4th grade days of trading fighter jet cards...

"An F16 for a Harrier? No ways, you've got to throw in at least a Mig 27...'

Comment: @Kurt Human Exactly! Those were the days! Basically, Shaun has created a virtual playground for us! Great stuff!

Answer (score 0):

Great! I was thinking and imaging something like that for quite some time now but never tried to set it up. Maybe could evolve something more social/community.. Who knows. 
See you there ;)